# How to send mails to diferent sales representatives for diferent stores?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, multistore

I have an issue with my sales representatives emails in Magento version 1.9.3.2.

I have 2 stores in my site and I have created different transactional emails for each store.

When I check `Use Website` checkbox  at `System-Configuration-General-Store Email Addresses` and at `System-Configuration-Sales-Sales emails` all transactional emails was sent without problems.

Due to this behavior I have deduced that my mails and cron systems are correctly setup.

But when I try to set a different sales representative for each store following [Documentation](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/configuration/email-addresses.html), Magento don't send any email.

What can I do to send different emails to each sales representative?

Thanks in advance.